# Can't Extend Oracle Linux Partition

Tags: rhel, partition, storage, oracle-linux

I've been struggling to extend the `sda3` partition shown below to the max available on `sda` which is `100G`. I wasn't aware my distro was Oracle Linux & I was trying all the solutions available for RHEL from other sites.

```
[root@localname bin]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─sda2   8:2    0    8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0 38.4G  0 part /
└─sda1   8:1    0  200M  0 part /boot/efi
```

I can't however find anything yet & thought to seek community's help here directly. Can someone help me out here in extending the partition `sda3` to the maximum capacity what `sda` actually holds?

**Fdisk Output:**

```
[root@localname bin]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1    97677311    48838655+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

FDISK done separately on each device gives the relevant info, but fdisk as a whole will only show the first partition details as mentioned above.

```
[root@localname bin]# fdisk -l /dev/sda2

Disk /dev/sda2: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 1048576 bytes

[root@localname bin]# fdisk -l /dev/sda3

Disk /dev/sda3: 41.2 GB, 41209036800 bytes, 80486400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 1048576 bytes
```

Comment: Seems strange to me that `sda2` appears before `sda3`... can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, edited the question.

Comment: it seems the output is incomplete, could it be? It doesn't show the other partitions

Comment: That's the full output; nothing left.

Comment: Mmmh, maybe the vesion of fdisk doesn't suppot GPT...

Comment: Added new info; fdisk done separately on each device details them.

Comment: Let's try with `parted -l`. I suspect `sda3` is between `sda2` and `sda1`, therefore knowing when each partition starts and end will prove if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ok. So it seems the GPT table wasn't at the back of the table. Updated the question. The actual size is still the old one, not increased to the max it should be.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong...

Comment: You cannot mess with a disk's partitions while ANY of the disk's partitions is mounted. Boot from a Live CD/USB, there's even a parted-specific Live Boot on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever `fdisk` shows you a partition with `ee` in the Id field, that indicates the actual partitioning type is GPT and this version does not support it. Partition ID code `ee` is a dummy MBR partition entry that exists in all GPT-partitioned disks. Modifying it has no effect on the real GPT partition table.

In this case, you must use `parted` or `gdisk` instead of `fdisk`.

Running `fdisk -l /dev/sda2` and `fdisk -l /dev/sda3` will only produce nonsense, because those commands will be reading the first block of the respective partition and interpreting it as the partition table. Any changes applied there will not have any effect on the real partition table.

Remember: any commands that manipulate disk partitions should always be targeted to the device that contains the actual partition table. Almost always this will be the whole-disk device.

Extending the 3rd partition is possible only if that partition is physically located after all the other partitions. Usually it's better to boot the system into rescue mode from the OS installation media or use another live Linux boot media, but it *is* possible to modify the partition table while the disk is in use. There are just three constraints:

- you should not change the disk location of the starting point of any of the partitions you wish to keep
- you should not make any of the partitions smaller than the filesystem is currently sized as
- to make the changes effective on a disk that is currently in use, you must often use the `partprobe` command or reboot: if your `fdisk` does not understand GPT, it indicates this system is probably RHEL/OEL 6.x or older, and that also means the partitioning tools might not be able to make partition changes effective immediately if the disk is in use.

The commands required to extend the third partition using `parted` would be:

```
# parted /dev/sda
(parted) print      

<read the output to confirm that the third partition is physically the last one>

(parted) resizepart 3 100%
(parted) quit
```

After this, check `/proc/partitions` to see if the kernel has already recognized the new size for the 3rd partition. If not, run `partprobe /dev/sda` and check again. If it's still not recognized, you may have to reboot.

Once the new partition size is recognized in `/proc/partitions`, it is time to extend the filesystem inside the partition. That must be done using a filesystem-specific tool, as RHEL/OEL 6.x is probably too old to have a generic `fsadm` tool. The filesystem type on such a system is probably `ext4`, and so `resize2fs` will be the tool to use. So run this command:

```
resize2fs /dev/sda3
```

The new size will be visible to commands like `df` only after the **filesystem** is successfully resized.

Comment: I had tried this already, `resize2fs` doesn't work here. Got the working solution in the answer I posted below.

Comment: Hmm... according to the second link you posted in your answer, the messages of `oci-growfs` look very similar to what `xfs_growfs`, the extension tool for XFS filesystems, would output. Perhaps it's an XFS filesystem after all? For comparison: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-grow-extend-xfs-filesytem-in-centos-rhel-using-xfs_growfs-command/

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a util which I got while searching & that resolved the issue like anything. No `umount` or check partitions in `/proc/partitions` for that matter.

Here are the 2 links that helped:

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/References/ociutilities.htm#OCI_Utilities

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/References/oci-growfs.htm#ocigrowfs